# How to replace values with their mean?

Tags: r

I have two matrices

```
 A = matrix(c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),nrow=3,ncol=2) 
> A
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    2    3
B = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7),nrow=3, ncol=2) 
> B 
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    4    5
[3,]    3    7
```

take the mean of all values in B that correspond to 3 in B:
Create a matrix with only the means:
Wanted matrix:

```
    C

        [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    3    4.3
 [2,]    3    4.3
 [3,]    3    4.3
```

Comment: in your calculations when do you use the matrix `A` ? have a look at `colMeans`

Comment: Not clear how this has any connection with `A`.  You can get the same result with `matrix(colMeans(B)[col(B)], ncol=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the groups are not column specific this might help:

```
A <- matrix(   c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),nrow=3,ncol=2) 
B <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7),nrow=3, ncol=2) 
C <- matrix(nrow = dim(A)[1], ncol=dim(A)[2])

groups <- unique(c(A))
for(group in groups) {
  C[which(A==group)] <- mean(B[which(A==group)])
}
```

If A contains `NA`values, then use

```
groups <- na.omit(unique(c(A)))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
A <- matrix(c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), nrow=4, ncol=2) 
B <- matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 4, 2), nrow=4, ncol=2) 

matrix(tapply(B, A, mean)[as.character(A)], nrow=nrow(A))
```

?